# Preprocessing and feature selection in a custom keras layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am participating in [this ASL fingerspelling Kaggle Competition](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/asl-fingerspelling/).

We are given a collection of phrases like "9560 plano".  Each phrase has a table associated with it.  The rows of the table are frame numbers of a video.  The columns are the x, y, and z coordinates of 1630 points on a human body.   The goal of the competition is to create a model which will recover the phrase from the table.

I have a model which works okay, but it requires some preprocessing of the data.

In particular, I

- Identify which hand is being used to spell the phrase.
- If it is the left hand, I reflect the hand in the yz plane, and overwrite the righthand coordinates with these new coordinates.  Essentially this makes everyone "right-handed" in my model.
- I then subtract the vector pointing to the wrist from the vector pointing to each point in the right hand.  This "stabilizes" the hand.
- In the end I only have 60 features I care about (right_hand_x_1, right_hand_x_2, ..., right_hand_z_20).

I would like to make a Layer subclass which does this preprocessing.

I don't expect you to do all of this.  I instead request a minimal working example which does something similar.

Please give code for a keras Layer subclass which will:

- take a 2x4 2D input tensor

| col 1 | col2 | col3 | col 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | c1 | d1 |
| a2 | b2 | c2 | d2 |

- if c_1 > b_1 returns the 2x3 tensor

| col 1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | c1 - b1 | d1 - b1 |
| a2 | c2 - b2 | d2 - b1 |

- if c_1 < b_1 returns the 2x3 tensor

| col 1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 - c1 | b1 - d1 |
| a2 | b2 - c2 | b2 - d2 |

Comment: I assume you have a typo in the last column of the second row in the middle table and it should read `d2 - b2` instead of `d2 - b1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`tf.matmul`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/matmul) to get both versions of new data (for cases where c < b and where c >= b). Then you can calculate the mask using tensor comparison. Lastly, use [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) to choose which version to use based on the mask value:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import keras as K
import numpy as np

class MyLayer(K.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tensor1 = tf.constant([
            [1, 0,  0 ],
            [0, -1, -1],
            [0, 1,  0 ],
            [0, 0,  1 ]
        ], dtype='float32')
        self.tensor2 = tf.constant([
            [1, 0,  0 ],
            [0, 1,  1 ],
            [0, -1, 0 ],
            [0, 0,  -1]
        ], dtype='float32')

    def call(self, inputs):
        assert(inputs.shape[-1] == 4)
        mask = tf.reshape(tf.repeat((inputs[:, 2] > inputs[:, 1]), repeats=3, axis=0), (inputs.shape[0], 3))
        return tf.where(mask, tf.matmul(inputs, self.tensor1), tf.matmul(inputs, self.tensor2))


inputs = tf.constant(np.random.randint(0, 20, size=8), dtype='float32', shape=(2, 4))
my_layer = MyLayer()
print('Input:\n', inputs)
print('\nOutput:\n', my_layer(inputs))
```

outputs:

```
Input:
 tf.Tensor(
[[ 0. 14. 10. 17.]
 [ 8.  9. 16. 13.]], shape=(2, 4), dtype=float32)

Output:
 tf.Tensor(
[[ 0.  4. -3.]
 [ 8.  7.  4.]], shape=(2, 3), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I am new to this site, but not to the SE network in general, and I am wondering if you have any insight into why my question was not well received?